# Does TLS 1.3 spec include additional privacy controls for avoiding URL category filtering?

Tags: tls, privacy, filtering

I've heard second-hand that the TLS 1.3 spec includes additional functionality to avoid URL category list filtering by firewalls and cloud-based proxies.  Is that correct?  If so, is there any documentation on how that works?

I can't seem to find any supporting documentation or information about this.

I'm wondering if TLS 1.3 could somehow be used to circumvent, say, web filtering for guest wireless applications; situations where the enterprise wouldn't have authority/control to implement SSL inspection on the guest user device.

Thoughts?

Comment: You might be thinking of ESNI, which is part of the TLS1.3 spec.  See https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-encrypted-sni/ for more info.

Comment: @mti2935: ESNI is from my understanding not part of the TLS 1.3 spec.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks.  I suppose it would be more accurate to say that [ESNI is an extension to TLS 1.3](https://blog.cloudflare.com/encrypted-sni/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Plain TLS 1.3 still has the domain name visible in clear in the TLS handshake, i.e. domain based categorizing and filtering is still possible. Extensions to TLS 1.3 can hide the domain though.

In detail:

Up until and including TLS 1.2 the server certificate was visible in clear in the TLS handshake. Since it includes the domain it could be used for filtering. With TLS 1.3 the encryption starts earlier in the handshake and includes also the (now encrypted) certificate.

The ClientHello (first message in handshake from the client) includes also the domain name as part of the [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) which is needed to support multi-homed servers were multiple domains and certificates are behind the same IP address. It was discussed to have this part encrypted too in TLS 1.3, but did not made it into the standard. Instead ESNI (Encrypted SNI) and ECH (Encrypted ClientHello) were developed to address this issue - learn [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/what-is-encrypted-sni/) for more.